# Using Moq with Windsor

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, moq, castle-windsor

I'm trying to set up some Moq repositories to test my service with Castle Windsor as my IOC. In general I use next structure:

```
WindsorContainer.Register(
    Component.For<IValidation>()
    .Named("Type1Validation")
    .LifestyleSingleton()
    .Instance(_type1ValidationMock.Object));
```

In most cases it is good but if I have more classes that implements *IValidation*. Let say that I have *Type1Validation* class and *Type2Validation*. I want to separate them during creation and during validation.

This is an example of code that I want to validate in unit test:

```
foreach (var validation in Container.ResolveAll<IValidation>()
                    .OfType<Type1Validation>())
{
    validation.Validate(somethingToValidate);
}
```

But with configuration of container mock. It cannot be done. Any help?

Comment: I tried your code and it worked, a Type1Validation object was returned. Why do you say it cannot be done?

Comment: You also might want to take a look at AutoFixture. http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/08/19/AutoFixtureasanauto-mockingcontainer/ This will need some adaptation for windsor, but that shouldn't be really hard.